# How to Initialize Tabbed Content outside Tabbed Container in jQuery UI tabs?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Is it possible and if so, how would you initialize tabbed content outside of the tabs container element?

The documentation all includes the tabs and the tab content in the same container, example:

```html
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab1">
        Tab 1 content
    </div>
    <div id="tab2">
        Tab 2 content
    </div>
    <div id="tab3">
        Tab 3 content
    </div>
</div>
```

However, for the project I'm working on, the navigation and the tab content are not located within the same container, thus:

```html
<nav id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
...
<article>
    <section id="tab1">
        Section 1 content
    </section>
    <section id="tab2">
        Section 2 content
    </section>
    <section id="tab3">
        Section 3 content
    </section>
</article>
```

Comment: Is it possible to contain both the nav. and the contents in a container, and `tabs()` it?

Comment: @Halil That's half of my question: Is it possible to do jQueryUI tabs without putting both in the same container? I know you can do this with the flowplayer tabs(), but it would be great if this functionality was available in the jQuery UI. Currently it seems that you have to either put both the tab nav and tab content in the same container, or have jQuery do it behind the scenes, which isn't really a great solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the source code of [`tabs`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/c1cda180a93a6c0a63cf21a68dacb54233e03d03/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js) (Lines [228](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/c1cda180a93a6c0a63cf21a68dacb54233e03d03/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js#L228) and [233](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/c1cda180a93a6c0a63cf21a68dacb54233e03d03/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js#L233)), it seems impossible to do this without some sort of "hack" like cloning the navigation as William Niu suggests, or containing both the navigation and the panels inside a common container, etc. The current iteration of `tabs` looks for the tab panels inside the parent element; i.e. it uses `find()`.

But I'm still hopeful that you can use a common container, it looks like you can place the navigation (and panels) anywhere inside the container ([L215](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/c1cda180a93a6c0a63cf21a68dacb54233e03d03/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js#L215)), and you don't have to place the container next to or near the navigation or panels, e.g. the actual tab elements can be deep within the container.

**Update:** Now there is an official way to do this: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7715

Comment: I ended up being able to get the navigation into a common container (<article>) along with the content. While having jQuery clone the object to achieve the result is the only reasonable solution if you can't use a common container, it's not a good solution, so to me there are only 2 decent ways to handle this: 1) Put the tabs and tab content in a container, 2) use flowplayer .tabs() rather than jQuery UI tabs. flowplayer tabs has the ability to assign tab content anywhere.

Comment: AFAIK, using anything as a container for jQuery UI tabs has no implications other than styling, and this is so if you use an UI theme. So it looks like even `body` can be used as a container. I assume you have tried that as well? Anyway it could be of use if one has to use a jQuery UI solution.

Comment: This answer helped me as I was trying to get this behavior as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this would work for you, but one solution would be to access an element that does contain both.

for example

```
$( "#tabs").parent().tabs();
```

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kedvU/2/)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want it to have that look to the user, you could clone the navigation bar to somewhere else and remove the original one.

```
$('#tabs').tabs();

// clone the navigation bar and put it in the placeholder
var copy = $('#tabs').clone(true).attr('id', 'placeholder');
copy.find('div.ui-tabs-panel').remove();
$('#placeholder').replaceWith(copy);

// remove the original navigation bar
$('#tabs > ul').remove();

$('#placeholder li > a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active');
});
```

See this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/QAJ2Z/1/.